# DirectoryInfo.getFiles beginning with

Tags: c#, directoryinfo

I've come across some strange behavior trying to get files that start with a certain string.

Please would someone give a working example on this:

I want to get all files in a directory that begin with a certain string, but also contain the xml extension.

for example:

```
 apples_01.xml
 apples_02.xml
 pears_03.xml
```

I want to be able to get the files that begin with apples.

So far I have this code

```
 DirectoryInfo taskDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(this.taskDirectoryPath);
 FileInfo[] taskFiles = taskDirectory.GetFiles("*.xml");
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
FileInfo[] taskFiles = taskDirectory.GetFiles("apples*.xml");
```

Comment: Simplicity is the best answer. For more complex scenarios you may use a regular expression after retrieving all the files

Comment: GetFiles can be unreliable as it searches both the shortname and long name. I would second the recommendation to .GetFiles() and then filter using a regular expression. (Better yet, use the new .EnumerateFiles() in .net 4)

Answer (score 6):

```
var taskFiles = taskDirectory.GetFiles("*.xml").Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("apples"));
```

Comment: `var _FileInfoArray = _DirectoryInfo.GetFiles("*.txt").Where(x => x.Name.Contains(_FileName));`